# Copy a table from Excel to Word then back to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a table from excel to word and then back again to excel using VBA. I have a script to do both of those things but how can I make the copy from word back to excel from the active word file that got created with "Copy2word" so that I dont have to specify the location of the word document in "Copy2excel"?

```
Sub Copy2word()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wkSht As Worksheet

    '\\ Stay on any sheet from which you want to copy data
    Set wkSht = ActiveSheet
    wkSht.UsedRange.Copy

    '\\ Start word and create new document to paste data
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wdApp Is Nothing Then
      Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      wdApp.Visible = True
    End If
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

    '\\ Paste Data from Excel
    wdDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, True

    '\\ Stop Excel's cut copy mode
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    MsgBox "Copy to Word Finished!", vbInformation, "Copy to Word"
End Sub


Sub Copy2excel()
    Const DOC_PATH As String = "C:\Users\MASS\Desktop\Test\TK1.docx"

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim rng As Range, t As Word.Table

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = False
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(DOC_PATH, ReadOnly:=True)

    Set sht = Sheets("Sheet4")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A20")
    sht.Activate

    For Each t In WordDoc.Tables
        t.Range.Copy
        rng.Select
        rng.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, _
                    DisplayAsIcon:=False
        With rng.Resize(t.Rows.Count, t.Columns.Count)
            .Cells.UnMerge
            .Cells.ColumnWidth = 14
            .Cells.RowHeight = 14
            .Cells.Font.Size = 10
        End With

        Set rng = rng.Offset(t.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
    Next t
    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: If you make `Copy2word` a function then it can return a reference to the Word doc it creates - then you can use that as the source in `Copy2excel`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, how would I go about doing that? I'm quite new with VBA

Comment: What's the purpose of the round-trip?  Are you just copying the table to Word then straight back to Excel, or is there some intermediate thing between those two actions?  It's difficult to make a useful suggestion without knowing what the use-case is.

Comment: Yeah the table has conditional formatting in excel, but I wish to do further analysis on the color-coded data. As its conditional formatting in Excel its sort off not really colored. Hence, by copying the table to word and back  to excel the cells actually have the color gotten from the conditional formatting.

Comment: You can get the conditional coloring directly in Excel VBA using `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` without the round-trip to Word  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat